# Disabling a button if textbox is empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to find out if I can create a real time event that would check for value of a textbox. What I mean is if the textbox is empty the button wouldnt be clickable. I am thinking is there anyway apart from validation to do this in code?

So far im stuck here:

```
if (YourName.Text = null)
{
       SubmitButton.Enabled = "False";
}
```

Where Yourname is the textbox and SubmitButton is the button :)

Comment: are you wanting this to occur on the page postback? or would you like this done on the client side? e.g. via javascript

Comment: If you want it to be real time, its better to do it in javascript. Because once disabled, the button stays disabled till the page is postbacked to server. So if the button is which initiating the postback, users wont be able to postback in the first place.

Comment: Probably a typo but it should be `if (YourName.Text == null)` with the double ==

Answer (score 10):

`System.String` provides a pair of convenient functions called [`IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) and [`IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) which you can use for testing for all kinds of strings that look empty to end users:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(YourName.Text)) {
    SubmitButton.Enabled = false; // <<== No double-quotes around false
} else {
    // Don't forget to re-enable the button
    SubmitButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

This would disable the button even for string composed entirely of blank characters, which makes sense when you validate a name.

The above is identical to

```
SubmitButton.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(YourName.Text);
```

which shorter than a version with an `if`.

Comment: or `SubmitButton.Enabled = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(YourName.Text)` :)

Comment: @TimBJames Perfect comment! You're right, the code without an `if` is cleaner (and it also fixes a bug).

Comment: @user2347308 You are welcome! If you no longer looking for an improved answer, consider accepting an answer by clicking the check mark next to it. This would earn you a badge on Stack Overflow.

Comment: These do not work for me. I can still click on my button and have the code fail because nothing is returned as a result of the empty text box. Any workaround?

Comment: Also, where do you put this snippet? If you put it in the page load method, the page never loads.

Answer (score 2):

```
SubmitButton.Enabled = YourName.Text.Length > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, start with the button disabled. Add TextChanged event to the textbox. And each time, check if the string is empty or not (use @dasblinkenlight's code in the TextChanged event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an old school javascript approach. You could use jquery but if this is all you want to do that would be overkill. In the code below, the `oninput` event fires when text is changed either via the keyboard or mouse/tap (you need to capture all, this should do that for you). The javascript then gets the contents of the textbox, removes preceeding and trailing whitespace, and sets the disabled attribute on the submit button equal to the textbox being empty, qualified with `.length == 0`.

Note: if you do not want to disable for text that is only whitespace change `submit.disabled = (tb.value.trim().length == 0);` to `submit.disabled = (tb.value.length == 0);` which removes the call to the trim() method. The trim() method strips the preceeding and trailing whitespace.

This approach removes the need for a postback to enable or disable the submit button.

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- tested in firefox -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var enableInput = function() {
            var tb = document.getElementById("text_box");
            var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
            submit.disabled = (tb.value.trim().length == 0); 
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="text_box" name="test" oninput="enableInput();"></input><br/>
        <input id="submit" type="submit"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```